# How to make loopable string list in R?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to make a minimum example for the data set of my other question. 
Currently, I have the following which is too complicated and errorprone for having a list of filenames and appending them for full filenames

```
data = read.csv("/home/masi/dataList.csv",header = FALSE,sep = ",")
i = 1
for (d in data) {
        data[i] = paste("/home/masi/Documents/CSV/", d, sep="")
        i = i + 1
}
```

dataList.csv

```
P103C1.csv
P103C2.csv 
P111C1.csv
```

Pseudocode to have in columns the thing first and transpose but you still cannot loop it as `for (d in data) {...}`; and appending once again

```
data = t(c("P103C1.csv" "P103C2.csv" "P111C1.csv"))

i = 1
for (d in data) {
        data[i] = paste("/home/masi/Documents/CSV/", d, sep="")
        i = i + 1
}
```

Actually, I think having the transpose there is not a good idea and a better and simpler method should exist.

**Expected output**: something equivalent to `data = read.csv("/home/masi/dataList.csv",header = FALSE,sep = ",")`.

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.1.1

Comment: your question isnt clear at all.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli I added an expected output. Can you specify what is not clear?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you! I removed it from comments and added it explicitly as own block.

Comment: Do you want to make a list of files you want to read in R. And Do you want to make a string that you can put in loop which will read these csv files.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Goal is to make a list of lists i.e. to read 1D signals to the list such that I could do statistical analysis to them. I am open to differential solutions, because clearly, my pseudocode is not the optimal here. - - I think the latter can be very effective, but your former is really the goal.

Comment: You need to make a list of datalist.csv such that you can feed each element directly into `read.csv`. if strings are already present in datalist.csv then you dont need to create a string again.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Can you please show it as an answer so I can be clear what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a string in this case as you already have all the files in datalist.csv. Create a list out of datalist.csv and then feed into a loop.

```
listoffiles=list("P103C1.csv","P103C2.csv","P111C1.csv")
files=list()

for(i in 1:length(listoffiles)){
    files[[i]]=read.csv(listoffiles[[i]], header = F, sep = ',')
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Only the separator has to be blank `sep = ""` for the thing to work.